How to pass part of a page path using Go Route when using universal routes?
When using universal links and Go Router if I have a webpage such as www.mywebsite.com/factfile/MickeyMouse please can you tell me how to pass the string "MickeyMouse" to a class? (or how to send the whole page path and I can just extract the string after the forward slash in the class?)
I was thinking something like:
final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'factfile/*',
          builder: (_, __) => ShowFactfile(path:path),
          ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

Thank you for any pointers,
N

I think you would just use:
GoRoute(
          path: 'factfile/*',
          builder: (_, state) => ShowFactfile(path: state.path), 
          ),

I got it from the GoRouter documentation. They have more ways of getting the url path other than state.path.
This will probably give you factfile/MickeyMouse so you can split the string and extract MickeyMouse like:
state.fullPath.split('/')[1]


Thank you @tbold my flutter is saying that the named parameter 'path' is not defined. Please can you tell me how to define it in the "ShowFactfile" class? (I think this is the problem, not that I haven't already created/initialised the variable)

@Nibbles Isn't ShowFactfile widget a custom widget? If path is a named parameter, the widget should look something like: const ShowFactfile({path: string}) <- note the curly braces. And you have to construct it like ShowFactfile(path: state.path). If it is a positional parameter then it will look like: const ShowFactfile(path: string)  and you can construct it like ShowFactfile(state.path)

Hi @tbold ShowFactfile is a Class

class ShowFactfile extends StatelessWidget {
@override
builder:           return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text(path),
),

(for the test I'd just like to display the page path as the title of the next screen)

Thank you for your help @tbold I've asked a separate question for the next step as I think this post was becoming unclear -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78854723/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-class
