How to pass a variable to a class?
I'd like to save the path name as a variable, go to a class and display the path name (as the app bar title). When I try to do this I get an error "the named parameter 'path' isn't defined" for the below line of code:
builder: (_, state) => ItemDetails(path: state.path),

Please can you point me in the right direction? This is the code:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router));
}

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'jobs/*',
          builder: (_, state) => ItemDetails(path: state.path),
          ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class ItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {

  Map routeData = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    routeData = ModalRoute
        .of(context)
        ?.settings
        .arguments as Map;

    final Query docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Collection_Name").where(
        "path", isEqualTo: path);

    return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: docRef. get (),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(path),
            ),
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(path),
            ),
            body: Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}")),
          );
        } else {
          var querySnapshot = snapshot.data!;
          var docs = querySnapshot.docs;
          final data = docs[0].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          final yourScrollController = ScrollController();
          return Scaffold(

              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(path),
              ),


You need a constructor with a named parameter for ItemDetails:
class ItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  // a new variable to store parameter received by constructor
  final String path;
  // constructor that has 1 named parameter called path
  ItemDetails({required this.path});
  
  Map routeData = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  /// ... everything else
 }
}

The squiggly parenthesis {} says there is a required parameter called path and it must be defined with a name when the constructor is being called. So using it like:
ItemDetails(path: state.path) is correct.
But using it like:
ItemDetails(state.path) will be incorrect.
Side note:
You can also define positional parameters like this:
class ItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  // a new variable to store parameter received by constructor
  final String path;
  // constructor that has 1 positional parameter
  ItemDetails(this.path);
  
  Map routeData = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  /// ... everything else
 }
}

And you would call it like:
ItemDetails(state.path)
There are pros and cons to both methods but in your case not much of a difference.

Thank you @tbold. For the line "final string path;" I am getting an error "Undefined class 'string'". I can replace it with "final path" to clear the error but when I run the app it crashes: ===== CRASH =====
si_signo=Segmentation fault: 11(11), si_code=SEGV_MAPERR(1), si_addr=0x27
version=3.4.1 (stable) (Tue May 21 15:46:25 2024 +0000) on "macos_x64"
pid=34684, thread=11043, isolate_group=main(0x7fe1a3833400), isolate=main(0x7fe1a3839200)
os=macos, arch=x64, comp=no, sim=no
isolate_instructions=10c4cc000, vm_instructions=109f7aaa0
fp=700001d095f8, sp=700001d095b8, pc=10c703ca1
... etc

@Nibbles whoops in dart string should be String. Sorry bout that. I will update the response

Thank you @tbold. If I use "final String path;" then I get a warning "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to a parameter type 'String'" for the line "builder: (_, state) => ItemDetails(path: state.path),". If I change "final String path;" to "final String? path;" then on run I get an error "Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "SocketException: Write failed (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32), port = 0".
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "SocketException: Write failed (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32), port = 0".
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "SocketExcept etc...

@Nibbles The first error says the value of state.path might be null. And making path nullable (final String? path;) is a valid way of getting around it. But the second error message doesn't have enough details so not sure exactly where it is failing. You should debug a bit more and post another question :) It could be due to path being null and in which case you should think what to do when path is null or empty string.
